# Create particular chapter titleformat style with tikz

Tags: titlesec, chapter-page

[image]

Hi, i'd like to reproduce this particular chapter title format. I'm a newbie to latex and i don't know very well how to use tikz (i saw some post in the forum using it), so i dont have a code to show you. Can someone give me a help by writing the code for me?

I'm using the book class and i'd like to use some color of mine for the box and for the mark "chapter" on the top of it.

Thanks in advance for those who will help!

Comment: This question could benefit from a minimal code that shows some attempt towards the stated goal.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt with `tikz` and `titlesec` packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
            {\sffamily}
            {}
            {0pt}
            {%
            \noindent%
            \begin{tikzpicture}%
                \node[above,yshift=4pt,font=\fontsize{15}{15}\mdseries] {CHAPTER};
                \node[xshift=0.15\linewidth,below right,text width=0.72\linewidth,font=\fontsize{28}{34}\bfseries] {#1};
                \node[below,fill=black,text=white,font=\fontsize{48}{48}\bfseries,inner sep=22pt] {\thechapter};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
            }
            []

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{70pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Stuff for the title}

    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \chapter{A long title with two lines}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    
    
    \chapter{Yet another long title with three lines of text}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: stuff1]

[image: stuff2]

[image: stuff3]